# reading lines using fscanf

Tags: c, std, scanf

hi i have a file which contains following lines:

```
wwa weweweof ewewe wdw:

      1    11 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  174.78.134.1  
      2    11 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  174.78.134.1 
      3     5 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  x58trxd00.abcd.edu.com [143.71.290.42] 
      4    11 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  174.78.134.1
```

i am using

```
    if(linecount == 8)
    while( fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %s %s  %s %s",&a1,&a2,&a3,&a4,&a5,&a6,&a7,&a8) != EOF ){  
          printf("%s",ch);
        } 

    else if (linecount == 9){
       while( fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %s %s  %s %s %s",&a1,&a2,&a3,&a4,&a5,&a6,&a7,&a8,&a9) != EOF ){  
          printf("%s",ch);
       }
    }
```

how do i check if the line rows in the file contain **8 or 9 elements**, so that i can run the above else-if statements accordingly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> reading lines using fscanf

***No.***

> But I though it was a good idea because...

***No.***

---

Reading lines is done using the `fgets()` function ([read the funny manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html)):

```
char buf[LINE_MAX];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) != NULL) {
    // process line here
}
```

Then, you can parse it using `sscanf()` (not preferred) or sane functions like `strchr()` and `strtok_r()` (preferred). It is also worth not(h)ing that the return value of `scanf()` ([docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fscanf.html)) is ***not*** `EOF`, but the number of entities successfully read. So, a lazy approach for parsing the string may be:

```
if (sscanf(buf, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", s1, s2, ...) < 9) {
    // there weren't 9 items to convert, so try to read 8 of them only
}
```

Also note that you better use some length-limitation with the `%s` conversion specifier in order to avoid buffer overflow errors, like this:

```
char s1[100];
sscanf(buf, "%99s", s1);
```

Likewise, you should not use the `&` address-of operator when scanning (into) a string - the array of char already decays into `char *`, and that is exactly what the `%s` conversion specifier expects - the type of `&s1` is `char (*)[N]` if `s1` is an array of N `char`s - and a mismatching type makes `scanf()` invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: thank you for the explaination, however how should i go about reading 8 elements if there is no 9 elements? is it using `else if ...<8)`?

Comment: @DeepakTivari You include 8 conversion specifiers instead of 9, perhaps?

Comment: however, my txt file can contain either 9 elemts 8 or even lesser elements, for case: 9 - i will get the ip address on the 9th element and store it, for case 8: i will get ip address at 8th element an store it, basically what matters is i extarct the ip address on either 8 or 9th element not others

Comment: @DeepakTivari You don't get me... First try converting 9 items. If that fails, then try converting 8. etc.

Comment: ok, seems i overlooked sscanf, last question, how would i store lets say s9 or s8 into a char[16] if i dont specify &s9 or &s8? thank you!

Comment: @DeepakTivari Well, you write `s9` instead of `&s9`, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Use `fgets` to get the line, and then do one `sscanf` to check for 9 elements, and if that fails then use `sscanf` again to check for the 8 element line.

If the format of the line is equal except one extra item, then remember that the `scanf` family of functions return the number of successfully scanned items. So it might be enough to just call `sscanf` once, and check if it returns `8` or `9`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `fgets()` function because your `swag` value in your array is currently set to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

and don't use `&` with `string` type (char arrays) data types with `scanf`

```
scanf("%s",name); //use it without "&" sign
```

**reason:**

A "string" in C is the address of a character buffer.
You want scanf to fill the memory in the buffer, which is pointed to by the variable.

In contrast, an int is a block of memory, not an address. In order for scanf to fill that memory, you need to pass its address.

Comment: This may be true, but you should explain why. As it stands this is just an unhelpful remark.