# Reading data from files, c

Tags: c, file

I practice the subject of files in c, and I am currently learning the basics, meaning I do not control all the functions built into the language, and in some commands, so if you can explain according to the basic commands and something complex I will thank you.

What the program does:
Absorption of students' data (identity card, name, and telephone), and print each student's data in the file (each student information will be written in a new line)

What's my problem with the code:
I wrote a function that prints out all the data in the file, if the user inserted more than one student, the function prints only the first line in the file and that is it.

When I used F10 I got to the loop while the first run printed out the details of the first student, and then the second run, the fscanf command returned a value (-1) and did not print out the details of the second student.

I would be happy to guide, and to correct.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct studnt
{
    int id;
    int number;
    char *name;
}typedef s_studnt;
void print_studnt(FILE *q,char name_file[])
{
    int id, number;
    char str_name[20];
    q=fopen(name_file, "r");
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        printf("eror fac\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n");
    while (!feof(q))
    {

        fscanf(q, "%d %s %d", &id, str_name, &number); //at the next loop, fscanf return -1
        printf("studnt name:%s\nthe id studnt:%d\ntelephon number:%d\n", str_name, id, number);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(q);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    int size, i, length;
    char str[20], name_file[20];
    FILE *q = NULL;
    s_studnt *studnt = NULL;
    printf("how much studnt you have:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    studnt = (s_studnt*)malloc(size * sizeof(s_studnt));
    if (studnt == NULL)
    {
        printf("eror 1\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("enter file name:\n");
    scanf("%s", name_file);
    q = fopen(name_file, "w");
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        printf("eror file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(q);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("enter studnt name:\n");
        scanf("%s", str);
        length = strlen(str);
        studnt[i].name = (char*)malloc(length+1 * sizeof(char));
        if (studnt[i].name == NULL)
        {
            printf("eror2\n");
            return 0;
        }
        strcpy(studnt[i].name, str);
        printf("enter the id studnt:\n");
        scanf("%d", &studnt[i].id);
        printf("enter your telephon number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &studnt[i].number);
        q = fopen(name_file, "a");
        if (q == NULL)
        {
            printf("eror write\n");
            return 0;
        }
        fprintf(q, "%d %s %d\n", studnt[i].id, studnt[i].name, studnt[i].number);

    }
    fclose(q);
    print_studnt(q,name_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One obvious thing to fix:  change `length+1 * sizeof(char)` to `(length+1) * sizeof(char)`.  Remember, multiplication groups more tightly than addition.  In this case, it doesn't really matter since `sizeof(char)` is 1, but as long as you're using it, use it correctly.

Comment: You are opening the file multiple times. Open it once outside the loop. Then write to it and close the file when you are done writing. What you did invoked implementation defined behavior and you used `while (!feof(q))`..wrong again. There are lots of thing to correctin your code - a book would help more than an answer.

Comment: @coderredoc  thanks, after I took the opening of the file from the loop it worked out.

Comment: See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @aviv.L.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code is working. you have to take care to open and close the file not too often i.e. within loops : open the file, do the looping and the close the file behind the loop.

then  there was a problem with `fscanf()`. `fscanf()` does read until the next whitespace so when you specify in the format of `fscanf()` `"%d %s %d"` it reads until the third whitespace and then stops. you can workaround this by the method in the code below  ( reading the return value of `fscanf()` ) because `fscanf()` returns `EOF` if it reads it ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ ) with the code below `fscanf()` continues scanning the file line-by-line until it reads `EOF`. reading files line-by-line with *fscanf()* is not considered to be good practice ( [reading lines using fscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098564/reading-lines-using-fscanf) )

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct studnt
{
    int id;
    int number;
    char *name;
}typedef s_studnt;

void print_studnt(FILE *q,char name_file[])
{
    int id, number;
    char str_name[20];

    q=fopen(name_file, "r");
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        printf("eror fac\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n");

    int r; 
    r=0;

    do
    {
        r = fscanf(q, "%d %s %d", &id, str_name, &number); 
        if(r==EOF) break;
        printf("studnt name:%s\nthe id studnt:%d\ntelephon number:%d\n", str_name, id, number);
        printf("\n");

    } while (r != EOF);
    fclose(q);
    return;
}


int main()
{
    int size, i, length;
    char str[20], name_file[20];
    FILE *q = NULL;
    s_studnt *studnt = NULL;
    printf("how much studnt you have:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    studnt = (s_studnt*)malloc(size * sizeof(s_studnt));
    if (studnt == NULL)
    {
        printf("eror 1\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("enter file name:\n");
    scanf("%s", name_file);
    q = fopen(name_file, "w");
    if (q == NULL)
    {
        printf("eror file\n");
        return 0;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        printf("enter studnt name:\n");
        scanf("%s", str);
        length = strlen(str);
        studnt[i].name = (char*)malloc(length+1 * sizeof(char));
        if (studnt[i].name == NULL)
           {
            printf("eror2\n");
            return 0;
           }
        strcpy(studnt[i].name, str);
        printf("enter the id studnt:\n");
        scanf("%d", &studnt[i].id);
        printf("enter your telephon number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &studnt[i].number);

        fprintf(q, "%d %s %d\n", studnt[i].id, studnt[i].name, studnt[i].number);

    }
    fclose(q);
    print_studnt(q,name_file);
    return 0;
}
```